# How to get title of fragment dialog window (app uses ActionBarSherlock)

Tags: android, android-fragments, gettext, actionbarsherlock

I need to compare strings from title of fragment dialogue with R.id.string from resources. It looks like smth like this (user Robotium).

> assertTrue(doesAlertTitleExist(getSolo().getString(R.string.error_dialog_title_text)));

But I can't get text from title of dialogue window fragment created with the help of ActionBar Sherlock. This code finds only views from screen over which this dialogue appears, but not views from dialogue.

You can find screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZkql.jpg

```
public boolean doesAlertTitleExist(String extectedTitle) {
    List<TextView> views = getDialogTextViews((ViewGroup) getSolo().getView(android.R.id.content));
    assertNotNull(views);
    for(TextView view : views){
        if(view.getText().toString().equals(extectedTitle)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private List<TextView> getDialogTextViews(ViewGroup view) {
    List<TextView> out = new LinkedList<TextView>();
    int count = view.getChildCount();
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        View child = view.getChildAt(i);
        if(child instanceof ViewGroup){
            out.addAll(getDialogTextViews((ViewGroup) child));
        }else if(child instanceof TextView){
            out.add((TextView) child);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: You should use `android-fragments` instead of `fragment` in the future. :)

Comment: What is `getSolo()`? Is this how you get your `DialogFragment` instance?

Comment: And why are you iterating through every view in the `ViewGroup`? Can't you use `findViewById` or `findViewByTag` instead?

Comment: No I can't. Because that dialogue was made from code and doesn't have proper name/tag/id in hierarchy viewer :( Programmers say that they won't remake all alerts to add IDs, because all of them will become custom and this could make problems with re-testing

Comment: Are you using the SherlockDialogFragment?  That may help.